# Definition of a Derivative - Polynomial Approximations

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question itself is rather simple - it is to utilize the definition of a derivative ($\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$) to find the derivative for the expression $x^5$, which from power rule we can obtain $5x^4$ or through the derivative definition by expanding the numerator.

However, my professor utilized a different approach to the problem (while still using the definition of a derivative as stated before) which baffled me, as shown below:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x + h)^5 - x^5}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^5(1 + \frac{h}{x})^5 - x^5}{h}$$
He then proceeded to utilize an approximation and somehow eliminated the exponent, which only furthered my confusion:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^5(1 + \frac{h}{x})^5 - x^5}{h}\approx\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^5(1 + 5\frac{h}{x}) - x^5}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^5 + 5hx^4 - x^5}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{5hx^4}{h}$$

And thereby got the result of $5x^4$. Can anybody explain this process? Is there a name to the process?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: $(1+\frac{h}{x})^5 = 1 + 5 \frac{x}{h} + O( h^{-2} )$.  The lower order terms die when you take the limit, so we don't bother writing them, I suppose.

Comment: I was thinking of the possibility of being able to disregard lower-order terms when taking the limit, could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @XanderHenderson It should be $5h/x$ and $\mathcal{O} (h^{2})$ (as you had it before I think?). And at Jerry, you aren't disregarding the _higher_ order terms in $h$. Remember, you are taking a limit as $h \to 0$, so for very small $h$, all the higher order terms in $h$ are _very_ close to $0$, so the expansion of $(1+h/x)^{5}$ is _very_ close to $1+5h/x$. If this is confusing, just expand $(1+h/x)^{5}$ explicitly to see what is going on.

Comment: @Mattos Sorry if I'm not catching it exactly as you meant, but is it due to the lower order of $x$ (when it is distributed) being "unnecessary" (insignificant to the limit) as it is multiplied by $x^5$?

Comment: @Mattos Indeed.  It is late, and I no brain good.  I know what I mean.  :\

Comment: @Jerrybibo I'm a bit confused about your question. Put it this way, expanding the bracketed term gives $$\left(1+\frac{h}{x} \right)^{5} = 1 + 5 \frac{h}{x} + 10 \left(\frac{h}{x} \right)^{2} + 10 \left(\frac{h}{x} \right)^{3} + 5 \left(\frac{h}{x} \right)^{4} +\left(\frac{h}{x} \right)^{5}$$ Now remember, you are taking the limit as $h \to 0$. When $h$ is _very_ close to zero, all those $h$ terms with powers (i.e $h^{2},h^{3}$ etc.) are even closer to $0$. As they contribute very little to the actual value of the sum, you can say that $$\left(1+\frac{h}{x} \right)^{5} \approx 1+5\frac{h}{x}$$

Comment: @Jerrybibo Glad to hear you got it. Just for future reference, the $\mathcal{O}(h^{2})$ term that Xander wrote before expresses the same idea, that out of the terms $$\left(1+\frac{h}{x} \right)^{5} = 1 + 5 \frac{h}{x} + 10 \left(\frac{h}{x} \right)^{2} + 10 \left(\frac{h}{x} \right)^{3} + 5 \left(\frac{h}{x} \right)^{4} +\left(\frac{h}{x} \right)^{5} = 1 + 5 \frac{h}{x} + \mathcal{O}(h^{2})$$ the dominating term as $h \to 0$ will be some constant times $h^{2}$.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks! I would have appreciated it more if you could sum that up in an answer though. If you don't feel like it it's fine, it's just that the comments are getting clogged.